# Struts 2 s:iterator: How to avoid name clashes?

Tags: struts2

As far as I see, `s:iterator` always pushes the current item into the OGNL Value Stack, even if I use the `var` attribute. This means that all the members of the current item become top-level OGNL variables inside the loop, potentially hiding the properties of the Action:

```
<s:property value="owner" /> <%-- From the Action --%>
<s:iterator value="projects" var="project">
    <s:property value="#project.owner" /> <%-- From the project, obviously --%>
    <s:property value="owner" /> <%-- Ops, also from the project! --%>
</s:iterator>
<%-- (Fun(?) fact: #project.owner is still accessible here) --%>
```

The objects we iterate through (often with multiple levels of nesting) has many properties, and their number can grow later. The danger of accidentally hiding properties is very real, and worse, adding properties to JavaBeans can break pages that were once working.

Am I missing something here? How do you iterate through complex objects with Struts 2 + JSP?

Comment: That's how you iterate over objects. You can refer to action properties using the #action variable. If you have multiple beans with the same property name then you must explicitly refer to them through a named variable. It's never been an issue for me, and I've had some ridiculously complex jsp pages.

Comment: When you say that it was never an issue for you, do you mean that you have always used `#action.foo` instead of `foo` inside those loops (good point BTW), or simply that you were lucky enough?

Comment: I mean that on the rare occasions an action property is shadowed by a bean property I refer to it directly. I've not found it common to have deeply-nested view needs where the beans are so similar they have duplicate property names.